# Can't login after adding script to /etc/profile.d

Tags: 12.04, bash, login, scripts, .profile

I have created a little script to add bookmarks in Nautilus to redirect users to network share. If I run the script manually, it works brillantly but as soon as I try to add it in /etc/profile.d, I can't connect to the computer. It seems that as soon as I do a loop or anything "fancy" like that, the script give an error. Here is an example if my currently working script :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Creating gtk-bookmarks if it doesn't exists
if [[ ! -f ~/.gtk-bookmarks ]]
then
        touch ~/.gtk-bookmarks
fi

# Adding bookmarks if not present
if ! grep -Fxq "smb://example.com/R03C01 Software:" ~/.gtk-bookmarks
then
    echo "smb://example.com/R03C01 Software:" >> ~/.gtk-bookmarks
fi
```

As soon as I had a function like this one :

```
####
# Function find_server_by_ip()
# Desc : This function find the server to use for the current host IP Address
# Parameters : None
# Return : echo Server to use
####
function find_server_by_ip()
{
        hostname_ip=$(hostname -I)
        IFS="."
        set -- $hostname_ip

        if [[ $3 -eq 78 ]]
        then
                echo "Server A"
        else
                echo "Server B"
        fi
}
```

...login stop working. What baffles me is that running this script with *bash add_shortcut.sh* or *./add_shortcut.sh* works fine...

Is it possible that we can't create functions, parse arrays or anything like that in a script called by /etc/profile? And in that case, where or how can I execute a login script for all the users connecting to the computer? Oh, by the way I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS!

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

EDIT : There is a pastebin of the script. I don't add it compeletly since the script comments are in french so...well, there it is : http://pastebin.com/71XzaBk6.

Answer (score 2):

Stuff in /etc/profile.d is probably sourced by your window manager when you log in, and that probably uses /bin/sh, so target a POSIX shell, not bash, for scripts to be added there. Note that `[[` is not found in the scripts that are in there now.

So,

- choose `[ ... ]` over `[[ ... ]]`
- use `funcname() { ... }` without the `function` keyword

dash is a POSIX (only) shell, so you might find the [dash man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dash.1.html) handy

---

Comments on http://pastebin.com/71XzaBk6

- This is the primary error: Change

  ```
  if [[ ! -f ~/.gtk-bookmarks ]]
  ```

  to

  ```
   if [ ! -f ~/.gtk-bookmarks ]
  ```
- the `find_server_by_ip` function can be simplified:

  ```
  findserverbyip() {
      case "$(hostname -I)" in 
          *[0-9].33.9.[0-9]*) share_server=serverB ;;
          *)                  share_server=serverA ;;
      esac
  }
  ```

  Also, this comment is misleading: the function returns nothing, it has a side effect.

  ```
  # Return : echo Server to use
  ```
- might as well remove the shebang line: this script doesn't get executed, it gets sourced.

Comment: Note that goes for your ~/.profile too.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Unfortunately I tried to remove everything not "sh"-compliant and still the same problem. I'm starting to think that the problem is caused by /etc/profile that "source" the script, not execute them alongside himself...??

Comment: show (or link to) the whole script.

Comment: I added a link to pastebin with the (almost) whole script in the question.